# What is the antonym of the prefix retro-?

Tags: antonyms, prefixes

A coworker and I are discussing the word "retromingent", which means urinating backwards.  We are wondering what the opposite would be: the word that means urinating forwards.

What is the opposite of the prefix "retro-"?

Comment: Where on *earth* did you encounter a situation where you needed to **use** this term?

Comment: Spiro Agnew used "retromingent" to describe the policies of some of his political opponents which were in his opinion backwards and destructive.  One of my coworkers uses it the same way, and it made me wonder what kind of a word we could use to describe policies which are forward-looking, yet still destructive.

Comment: .... metro? :-)

Comment: I agree with you that *pro-* and *antero-* are both worthy answers, with *pro-* slightly better.  Here is better support for *pro-* than merely a gathering of analogous forms: [History of Animals](http://books.google.com/books?id=rtXJmpDv1pIC&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=promingent&source=bl&ots=jjzfG8W3gK&sig=yva25S_D-WEvAnsH4o7NYpNQ45Q&hl=en&ei=4F56TsmEFoWNsQLXg8jFAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=promingent&f=false), which I found by Googling.  Another indication:  Check Google for hits on *promingent* versus hits on *anteromingent*.

Comment: @TomasT. *metromingent* just means when guys sit down to pee.

Comment: [Ortho-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortho), meaning correct or straight, would be another option, in opposition to the sense "bent back".

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Well, *retro-* comes from Latin, originally meaning backward, back, or behind. *Antero-* is used in some technical contexts (such as *anterograde amnesia*) but it's rather uncommon. It literally means *before* or *in front of*, as in the related *ante-* (vs. *post-*).

You might be looking for something more along the lines of *pro-* (or *progre-*). In short:

> *retro-* : *back* :: *pro-* : *forth*

Comment: Depending on technical context, I would expect *pro-* to be better understood. It has precedents in words like **prograde** and **retrograde**.

Comment: But *anteromingent* sounds so much cooler than *promingent*.

Comment: @Andrew Vit: While I think *pro-* is the appropriate answer, your precedents aren't as strong as they could be since Jon Purdy himself mentions *anterograde* in his answer.

Comment: @JohnY I'm not saying *antero-* is wrong: it's probably better suited for disambiguation of some terms. Generally speaking though, more people will know what you mean by *retrograde* rather than *anterograde*...

Comment: the convention of retro is predominant while the use of antero is (found to be) either out dated or least used (at least in British English.)

Answer (score 17):

I'd go with [antero-](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/antero-):

> a combining form with the meaning “situated in front, fore,” used in the formation of compound words
>    <sub>*from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/antero-)*</sub>

Comment: I like this option.  After studying Jon Purdy's answer, though, I think anteromingent would mean urinating in front of oneself, not urinating forward.  It's very similar, but has a subtle difference.  Still, +1 for the great prefix.

Comment: Yes very subtle for to arrive before or "in front of" the subject it (excrement) has to in fact be projected forward does it not? Moreover. your definition points to the subject "puddling" before himself to validate anteromingent rather than the actual process of urinating.

Comment: _antero-_ is more directly opposed to _postero-_ (from _ante_ / _post_).

Comment: Retroactively and proactively aren't really used as antonyms.

Comment: Isn't this creating more confusion than expected, if we look only at the analogy and what this wikipedia post suggests that **ante** in Latin means "before" - en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ante, so can anyone clarify with clear-cut distinction between **ante** and **retro** when both means something **before** or **back-in-time** ?

Answer (score 1):

Retro stands for something from yesteryear, most commonly used for style or fashion. In my opinion the antonym in that sense should be "modern"  or "prospective".

Comment: I'm fairly sure the OP was asking for a general prefix, not localized adjectives.

Comment: I was also looking for the opposite of a specific word, retromingent.  In this word, the retro part does not refer to yesteryear and is not used for style or fashion.

Comment: I paid attention specifically just to Retro. I am sorry. In this case I would agree with Jon. How about Non Retromingent?

Comment: No, I'm specifically looking for a word which would mean urinating forwards.  I believe it to be *promingent*, which is why I accepted that answer.

Answer (score -1):

Definition of AVANT:  culturally or stylistically advanced :  avant-garde avant jazz

Examples of AVANT
readers of this very avant novel should not expect to find much in the way of traditional narrative structure

Origin of AVANT:
French avant- fore-, front, from avant before, from Latin abante

Avant is evidently way out of what OP seeks as it denotes "progression" in a possibly "culturally" significant (increasingly figurative and least literal) semantical.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avant

Comment: -1 Duplicate answer of the -2 answer just below this.

Comment: This is interesting. To go "en avant" is advancing towards the future. However, "avant" means "before", hence the opposite of the future !

Answer (score -2):

Maybe avantmingent? You can check what The Merriam-Webster Dictionary says about avant, at: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avant