# Opposite of "retrofit"

Tags: antonyms

To retrofit is to take a new item and make it work with something old.

What is the word to take an old item and make it work with something new?

For example, someone could retrofit a new character by modding an old game. Retrofitting an old character into a new game doesn't sound correct, since you're doing the exact opposite of retrofitting. What word am I looking for?

Comment: "Modernize" and "upgrade" are the two that come immediately to mind. Are those close? "Recondition" and "Renovate" may also be suitable in some circumstances.

Comment: It's just a **reuse**. Read about 'new-life reuse where it is used for a different function' on WP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuse KitFox is on the spot with **repurpose**, wish that was suggested as the answer, not merely mentioned in the passing.

Comment: I think retrofit would apply with both. For example sentences like "standard 'dumb' bombs have been retrofitted with 'smart' guidance packages to improve their accuracy" perfectly describes taking something old and adding something new.

Comment: Taking an old item and using for something new, for new purpose, IS  one of the meaning of retrofit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that there may be no correct answer.
I looked up [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42752/what-is-the-antonym-of-the-prefix-retro), and it gave me pro- and antero- as antonyms.
Profit. No.
Anterofit. Doesn't even exist.

There may not be an antonym for this word. However, there's a myriad of other words that mean what you want, such as:

- Update
- **Refit**
- Modernize
- Renovate

Comment: _Refit_ seems like a fine opposite to _retrofit._ Not sure why you say there's no antonym. Just because the usual opposite of _retro-_ isn't productive here doesn't mean there's no antonym for the full word.

Comment: @BraddSzonye that's incorrect, refit (refit  rather means refubrish) and retrofit are near-synonyms. The OPs definition of retrofit is incorrect.

Comment: The problem is that if something has not been fitted in the first place, it cannot be "refitted". As far as bringing in a previous character into a game, I would "reintroduce X."

Answer (score 2):

I would normally just use *adapt*.

Of course, that's a hypernym of *retrofit*, but there's a good reason why we have a specific term for using something new in an older context; the challenges are different, because we can't plan for how to design the old context to work with the new component because the old context is by definition not what we are designing. Conversely, if we are using an existing component in a newer context (and indeed, we will be doing so almost every time; we'll always have some elements that pre-exist) we have the ability to plan the wider context to match well, which while still posing challenges, is generally more easily done.

This would cover physical items (adapting an engine component to work in a new engine), digital items (adapting a general purpose software library to better serve a specific use) or intellectual property (adapting an existing character or location, whether fictional or based on reality, to serve a game or narrative).

Answer (score 1):

*Recycle* is close in meaning to your context. It would be widely recognized as taking something used (old) for use in something new. It's not perfect, but it fits with the example you gave: I recycled some of the characters from the last game for the new game.

*Reuse* would also work but has less of a sense of modification or repurposing than recycle has.

And also, *repurpose* could be used, although I think this indicates that the thing is adapted for something other than its intended use. It would suit if you were using an old character as a statue, an image on a poster, or a coffee table, for instance.

Comment: +1 Isn't *repurpose* the word? Should it not have been *the* answer? :)

Comment: These words are all good if the old thing requires no modification; otherwise I'd prefer _refit._

Answer (score 1):

Military always uses term retrofit in opposite way you do. It's take old and add new components to it (essentially upgrade). Merriam-Webster's definition of *retrofit*:

1. to furnish (something, such as a computer, airplane, or building) with new or modified parts or equipment not available or considered necessary at the time of manufacture
2. to install (new or modified parts or equipment) in something previously manufactured or constructed *(the meaning you could misinterpret, watch what is the object of action)*
3. to adapt to a new purpose or need .

A synonym of retrofit(1) is to modernize. There is no one-word antonyms, but you could say "restore to original (factory) condition". Retrofit(2) probably can be antagonized by "strip". Retrofit (3) is repurpose, no idea what can be used as antonym, maybe "reassign to (old role)".

Answer (score 0):

A word often used in the area of electronic technology, such as in your game example is *Kludge*.  This is most often used when the old item is not quite perfect for the job.  It doesn't carry the negative connotation of words like *Bodge*.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-equipped?

"The car came pre-equipped for next year's technology"

Comment: Can you support your answer with references and argue why this is the right word?